# Downlaod speed with apt-get is very slow in Ubuntu 18.04 (1kb/s)

Tags: 18.04, apt, disk-usage, download-speed

I'm not sure what's the problem.
Internet speed 50Mbps while `apt` speed is 1k/s.

I tried many servers with the same result.

Could it be the storage space of boot section? (it report sometime that it's small)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be for a couple of reasons. Have you set a bandwidth limit in your `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades` file? If so, this will affect `apt`.

Otherwise:

1. Go to "System Settings" ⇢ "Software & Updates"
2. From the "Download from" dropdown, choose "Other". This will open another window.
3. Click the "Select Best Server" button in the upper right corner (this will take a while, as a series of tests will try to find the best server)

Hopefully one of these will resolve your issue.

Comment: Oh, yes, I was long time ago setting my limit in `76downlaod` to 1.
Opss, memory problem.

Comment: Glad this solved your problem. Cheers 